# Quancast GDPR Javascript

Tags: cookies

I am using [Quancast GDPR](https://www.quantcast.com/gdpr/quantcast-choice-self-serve/), for cookies, which give you a script to embed on my website, but nowhere on the web is there information on how to know if the user has marked an option or not,

Do you happen to know how this tool is used?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same dilemma :)

[Use this framework](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/CMP%20JS%20API%20v1.1%20Final.md)

[there are aids that can be used](https://help.sourcepoint.com/en/articles/2835223-using-__cmp-getvendorconsents-getconsentdata-to-retrieve-consent-information-and-getcustomvendorconsents-functions)